# How to define association on rule without tokens?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, yacc, happy

I have the following minimized grammar

```
Exp : let var '=' Exp in Exp end                     { App (Fn $2 $6) $4 }
    | Exp Exp                                        { App $1 $2 }
    | Exp OpCode Exp                                 { Op $1 Add $3 }
    | '(' Exp ')'                                    { $2 }
    | num                                            { Num $1 }
    | var                                            { Ident $1 }
    | '\\' var '.' Exp                               { Fn $2 $4 }
```

The `Exp Exp` rule is used to apply a function in a value. But if I have something like `myFunc 1 2` it defaults to precendence `myFunc (1 2)`, which is not what I want. I want `(myFunc 1) 2`, for currying.

But how can I define the association if I don't have a non-terminal symbol? Trying to do `%left Exp` don't seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really apply precedence or associativity unless you have a terminal to shift, because precedence and associativity rules are used to resolve shift/reduce conflicts. You don't necessarily need a terminal in the reduction, so you could use a fake terminal and write:

```
Exp: Exp Exp %prec CURRY
```

But that won't help you because there is no terminal to compare precedence with. Precedence relations are *always* a comparison between the precedence of the lookahead symbol (a terminal) and possible reductions (by default, the precedence of a reduction is based on the rightmost terminal in the rule, but as above you can explicitly specify).

Since you can't do it the short-hand way, you need to fallback to the old-fashioned style where you write an unambiguous grammar with explicit precedence rules:

```
Curry: Term
     | Curry Term
```

(That's left-associative, by the away. If `func 1 2` is parsed as `((func 1) 2)`, then application is associating to the left.)

Assuming that infix binds tighter than application, you'd then have:

```
Term: Value
    | Term Opcode Value

Value: '(' Exp ')'
     | num
     | var

Exp: Curry
```

(You'll have to figure out how to integrate lambdas into that. It depends on how you expect them to group, but hopefully the model above is clear.)

Comment: Why do you use Term, Value and Exp? Can you point me something to read to help me organize better my grammar?

Comment: @fotanus: Because I wasn't planning ahead. The names are really irrelevant: in complex grammars, I just number them. But they are essentially different precedence levels.  Here's an example of a C grammar with precedence fully written out: http://www.lysator.liu.se/%28nobg%29/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html